# git lfs locks works fine inside corporate network, but takes more than 10 minutes when used by contractor connecting through VPN

Tags: git, svn, vpn, git-lfs

Our contractors are migrating from SVN to Git, and we are in need to provide them with file locking option. As SVN supports this feature, git doesn't have one, so i'm trying to use Git LFS module for this problem. After installing GIT LFS, i locked some of the files using

```
    git lfs lock file
```

and typed command

```
    git lfs locks
```

it worked very fast, i got respond less then in a second.
But on the side of our contractors, who connect to our network through VPN, response time was more than 10 minutes, and still no output. What might be the problem? And is there any any to solve it?

Git itself and git lfs are installed on Windows 10 and all the commands are run from git bash terminal.
git lfs version 2.7.1

I expect same response time from git lfs lock

Comment: You can try running the command with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and see what the output tells you. This is likely to be some sort of network issue, though.

Comment: @bk2204
GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs locks gives:
trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
trace: exec: git-lfs locks
trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '-l'
trace git-lfs: creds: filling with GIT_ASKPASS: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass Username for "https://gitlab.com"
continuation in next comment

Comment: @bk2204
 trace git-lfs: credential fill error: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass": file does not exist
trace git-lfs: creds: git credential fill ("https", "gitlab.com", "")

other two commands respong forever, giving no output

Comment: @bk2204 git output says, that "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass": file does not exist
But actually, this file exists. Maybe this might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved, the problem was ni git version. Our contractors used 2.19, thay updated to 2.21.0.windows.1, and everything worked fine! Thanks everyone for help.